# Java graph library

Tags: java, graph

I've been looking around here for any reference to a java library for visual representation of graphs but I only find libraries for histograms, pie charts, and others.
I'm looking for a library for graphs, the ones with vertex, nodes and all that.
Anyone could recomend any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) java graph library. It has not only vertex and nodes, but also most common algorithms implemented like shortest path algorithms or algorithms for calculating graph properties - metrics like clustering coefficient, degree distribution. Its community is active and well responsive to question on user mail list.

Answer (score 3):

[jgraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) is promising. FYI, There's also JGraphT (but that's just for processing graphs not visualization.