# Java Directed Graph framework

Tags: java, user-interface, graph

I need to represent graphically a directed graph, with possibility of defining events when clicking the nodes.

But the library needs to be free, because it's for a professional purpose and I won't get lucky on getting a paid one.

Comment: Do you mean graphs having nodes and edges or do you mean charts?

Comment: jGraph? jFreeChart? No clue what kind of graph you're talking about.

Comment: Nodes and edges. A directed graph. jGraph is the mxgraph right? And isn't free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Java graph library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022289/java-graph-library)

[jGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) and [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) are both licensed under BSD.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, and yes I read the definition in wiki. But does that mean I could use it in an research project application?

In the jGraph I find only this:
http://www.jgraph.com/jgraphdownload.html

But that doesn't seem like the jGraph library that I've found examples of.

Comment: You can use it freely (even commercially). Basically the only thing you need to do is leave the original copyright notice somewhere in the Readme...

Comment: @Mind - it is not a good idea to seek (what amounts to) free legal advice from no-lawyers.  If you cannot get your head around what a license means, and you are worried about it, talk to a legal professional ...

Comment: Yeah, thanks to both of you. Your help was much appreciated!